# Xcode Device's "Replace Container" function replacing the container with incorrect permissions?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated to Xcode 15.0 and seem to be unable to use the Replace Container function to replace an app container. The device that the container is hosted on is running iOS 17. Similarly, editing the current run scheme and choosing a new App Data container fails with an identical error.

[image: Replace Container screenshot]

Replacing the container results in a slew of permissions related errors, namely "Permission denied".

```
Failed to create directory /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A3C32E7A-34F3-4C69-B037-478027F2A4AC/Library/Preferences because of 13.
Couldn't write values for keys (
    "/google/measurement/app_instance_id"
) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280a82760> (Domain: com.google.gmp.measurement, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): Directory needed
os_unix.c:47395: (13) lstat(/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A3C32E7A-34F3-4C69-B037-478027F2A4AC/Documents)
- Permission denied os_unix.c:47395: (13) lstat(/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A3C32E7A-34F3-4C69-B037-478027F2A4AC/Documents/<redacted>.sqlite)
- Permission denied os_unix.c:46898: (13) statfs(/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A3C32E7A-34F3-4C69-B037-478027F2A4AC/Documents/<redacted>.sqlite)
- Permission denied
```

Is anyone else encountering this issue? It looks like the Replace Container function still works on Xcode 14.3.1.

Comment: Asked on the Developer Forums as well: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738489

Comment: Same issue since XCode 15 - iOS 17. Replacing the Container messes up the permissions and app can't read anymore the directories

Comment: Still occurring on Xcode 15.0.1 and iOS 17.0.3. No reply on the Feedback Assistant report.

Comment: It looks like this is resolved in Xcode 15.1, according to the Xcode 15.1 beta 3 release notes.

Comment: Thank you for sharing Aaron. Looks like they also fixed the issue where files of a downloaded container were not visible. I was also experiencing this issue. I will try it as soon it gets out of the beta and report here my results

Comment: Update - this does not seem to be fixed in Xcode 15.1 (at least not in beta 3).

Comment: Have you also updated to latest iOS version? I will wait for the stable version to test.

Comment: Yes - I was updated to 17.1.1.

Comment: The bug is still not fixed with latest Xcode 15.1 RC1 released today... macOS Version 14.1.2 (Build 23B92), Xcode 15.1 (22502) (Build 15C65), iOS 17.2 Beta (21C5054b)

Comment: Tested on 15.1 and iOS 17.2 and still not fixed